Batch command to move files which names contain a certain amount of alphanumeric characters
I have hundreds of files that when created generate a random file name with either 15 character or 32 character. I need to target only the 32 character files to move. I need this to be a batch command. I have tried using "??"s and "**"s but neither work. Is there a character to use that signifies "any character". Again the files names are completely randomly generated alphanumeric no special characters. I appreciate any help, thank you.
@echo off
echo %cd%\AllFiles\


for /r %%d in (???????????????????????????????.pdf) do copy "%%d" "%cd%\AllFiles\"

This moves all pdfs even if name length is less that 32.

You should tag with whatever shell you use (cmd, powershell).

when there is \ in command it must be windows just a guess :D and OP is also saying batch command

I should mention, that your submitted code cannot copy/move any of the files with 32 character basenames. The reason for that is you appear to be using the string ???????????????????????????????.pdf, which covers up to 31 character basenames only. Submitting exactly the code you are having an issue with prevents typos and ensures that we are all working without assumptions.

What should be done if there is a duplicate filename?

A findstr approach:
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
for /r "%sourcedir%" %%e in (*.pdf) do ECHO %%~ne|FINDSTR /r /i /b /e "................................">nul&IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO copy "%%e" "%cd%\AllFiles\"

Note that I prefer to avoid the use of ADFNPSTXZ as metavariable names as these are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs, so I've used %%e.
I prefer for /r "%sourcedir%"… since it allows Space in the directoryname.
/x = /b /e if preferred.
Note that exactly 32 . will operate on filenames containing exactly 32 characters, not 31 or fewer, nor 33 or more.
Also, I've disarmed the code by merely echoing the proposed command for verification.
I'm concerned that since the code attempts to operate on %cd% and its subdirectories then once files have been moved to %cd%\allfiles you would then be attempting at some stage to operate on %cd%\allfiles\32-character.pdf which would generate error messages, regardless of whether the operation is move or copy.

You could use the where.exe utility, which, unlike everything else treating the ? wildcard as 0 or 1 character(s), treats it as exactly 1.
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R . ????????????????????????????????.pdf /F 2^>NUL') Do @Copy /Y %%G AllFiles

Please note that I used Copy above to match the code in your question, however to remain compatible with your question title and body text, you may wish to replace that command with Move.

As an additional note, because in your example the source root for your recursive search is the current directory, ., and the destination, AllFiles, is also in the current directory, you may need to exclude initial matches within that directory from the enumerated listing. You could do that by piping the where.exe results to findstr.exe:
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R . ????????????????????????????????.pdf /F 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRV "\\AllFiles\\[^\\][^\\]*$"') Do @Copy /Y %%G AllFiles

